# how to extract data from mongo collection for data warehouse use

Tags: mongodb, etl

My company starts to use mongo and we are starting to think about what is the best way to extract data from mongodb and send it to our data warehouse.

My question focus around the extract part of the process. As i see it, the best way is to expose API on the service that is built on top of mongo, that the ETL process (that is invoked by a job from the data warehouse) will execute with some specific query that will probably will query for set of times (i.e. - startdate and enddate for every record).

is that sound right or i am missing something or maybe there is better way than that?

initially i was thinking about doing mongoexport every X duration but according to the documentation it seems not so good performance wise.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

give a try to pentaho kettle.

https://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/creating-pentaho-reports-from-mongodb/

Comment: Hi, this is not so helpfull since it doesnt answer my question.

Comment: My advice is to not use the db engine as etl tool. Use kettle and schedule via carte server or cron.  Open kettle 4.4 and use the transformation steps Big Data/MongoDb Input and Output.

Comment: still, if I understand your suggestion - the schedule engine will issue a mongo query, correct?

Comment: the most common way is to export all the rows to kettle (with the kettle step import from Mongodb) and AFTER that , make your data crunching (queries or whatever) inside kettle. So you dont have to work in "hot" with real data. Just a FRESH DUMP of this data

Comment: Export data from mongo while in production and chunks are being balanced can be problematic + export has performance penalty. another issue is how you know which data you already exported?

Comment: i am not talking about native mongodb export, please, install kettle , and try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Alteryx Designer to extract from MongoDB with the dedicated connector and prep my data to load into Tableau, with optional data prep in between.
Works pretty well!
ALteryx can write to most DBs though...